# Android: Error on remove view

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

So I've got a piece of code that works on android 4.2, but doesn't work on older android versions.

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            try {
                ImageView ivCloudView = lCloudArray.get(iCloudCounter); // get View from ArrayList
                ((ViewGroup) ivCloudView.getParent()).removeView(ivCloudView); //remove View
                iCloudCounter++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work on older android versions. If I change the remove code, and replace it with something like:

```
ivCloudView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
```

It will work. I have no idea what wrong..

The imageviews (clouds) are created dynamically, and are put in the lCloudArray. But the strange part is, that when there is only 1 cloud in the field, it will be deleted without any problems. 
When there is multiple clouds, the errors start happening.

The xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/goededoelenquiz"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvgametitle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bStartbutton"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="75sp"
    android:text="@string/gametitle" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bStartbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/startbutton" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bHighscore"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/highscorebutton" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What are the errors?

Comment: probably you should print the stacktrace. Are you gettint IndexOutOfBOundException?

Comment: This is the error message i get http://gyazo.com/41baaf7da848e4b175f330271dd3b72c Fatal exception: main NullpointerException

Comment: is lCloudArray correctly initialized?

Comment: List<ImageView> lCloudArray=new ArrayList<ImageView>();

Comment: If I println(ivCloudView) I get: android.widget.ImageView@43e30600.. So I don't think it is null :/

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29 < this return a ViewParent and not a ViewGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess with the current information is that the ImageView (ivCloudView) doesn't have a parent. Check if ivCloudView.getParent() is not null before removing the view.

If this doesn't work, please post your layout XML!